# Read Specific Number of Files From External Storage Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Ok So what I want to do is I want to display only 3 files from external storage in recent tabs as you can see. I don't have much knowledge of android (java) so please help me.
Thank You!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vltmx.png)
Code:

```
     public ArrayList<File> findFiles(File file) {
        ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] files = null;
        try{
            files = file.listFiles();
            for (File singleFile : files) {
                if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()) {
                    arrayList.addAll(findFiles(singleFile));
                } else if(singleFile.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || singleFile.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")){
                        arrayList.add(singleFile);
 }
}
```

Comment: What has external storage to do with Recents?

Comment: You cannot just use the FIle class and File.list() to get 'Recents'. As what would that be? Which directory would you list?

Comment: Further: You are adding your files here `arrayList.add(singleFile);` What would be more simple then to check `arrayList.size()` and stop adding when you consider enough is enough.

Comment: Ey thanks ArrayList.size() works very well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, your `findFiles` method is passed a `File` which is a directory of 'most recent files' stored on the external directory? And your app has permission to read from external storage? Both are prerequisites for this to work.

You should definitely check that the parameter is a directory before calling `listFiles` since that function will return null if its not passed a directory. See [File#listFiles](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#listFiles()).

If you only want to add the first three JPEG files found you can just create an int variable (e.g. "count") outside the for loop, increment it each time a JPEG file is found, and break out of the for loop once you've found three matching files.

Also, you're missing `catch` and possibly `final` blocks, as well as a `return` statement at the end of the function.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my question or I didn't put it right. As you can see in the screenshot there are 5 files in the recent tab. I just want to show only 3 files because If I will run this on my phone then it's gonna take a lot of time to open because of all the recent files that's why I want to limit the number of files in the recent tab. Anyway Thanks for the Help I will see the try-catch block :)

Comment: `there are 5 files in the recent tab.` That can be. But where do these files come from? What is their absolute path or in which directory do they reside? It is pretty unclear which value of `file.getAbsolutePath()` you use when you call `findFiles(File file)`./ And you still left the question `What has external storage to do with Recents? –` unanswered. You cannot just use the FIle class and File.list() to get 'Recents'. As what would that be?

Comment: fileList.addAll(findFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())); all the files are coming from here means all the files which is availble in external storage will be seen in recent tabs whether it is .jpg, .apk .mp4 etc

Comment: Why the hell are you showing files from external storage in a Recents tab? They have nothing to do with recent use. And you would call that a file manager?

Comment: Your question and comment on my answer are definitely unclear and contradictory. Displaying file icons on a screen versus writing a function to return a list of files are two very different things. And I will echo the sentiments of other comments questioning why you have "recent" anything in external storage. If your question is "how do I only return the first 3 files in a directory" then my answer is correct.